# Need to categorize array according to specific ids

Tags: javascript, sorting, mapping

Hello I working in java script & having issue to sort the values and get sum by categories right now i have hotel_id and category_id.

```
    let myarray = [
  {
    price: 257,
    category: 1,
    hotel_id: 4
  },
  {
    price: 493,
    category: 1,
    hotel_id: 3
  },
  {
    price: 514,
    category: 1,
    hotel_id: 3
  },
  {
    price: 257,
    category: 1,
    hotel_id: 3
  },
{
    price: 104,
    category: 1,
    hotel_id: 3
  },
  {
    price: 295,
    category: 1,
    hotel_id: 3
  },
  {
    price: 125,
    category: 1,
    hotel_id: 2
  },
  {
    price: 125,
    category: 1,
    hotel_id: 2
  },
  {
    price: 157,
    category: 1,
    hotel_id: 2
  },
  {
    price: 125,
    category: 1,
    hotel_id: 2
  },
{
    price: 125,
    category: 1,
    hotel_id: 1
  },

  {
    price: 43,
    category: 1,
    hotel_id: 1
  },
  {
    price: 43,
    category: 2,
    hotel_id: 1
  },
  {
    price: 43,
    category: 2,
    hotel_id: 1
  }
];

var hotel_to_values = myarray.reduce(function (obj, item) {
    obj[item.hotel_id] = obj[item.hotel_id] || [];
    obj[item.hotel_id].push(item.category);
    return obj;
}, {});

var hotels = Object.keys(hotel_to_values).map(function (key) {
    return {hotel_id: key, category: hotel_to_values[key]};
});
```

I need to sort or group by something like this

- hotel 1

  - category 1

    - price 20
  - category 2

    - price 20 , price 30

right now my result is

```
[
    {
        "hotel_id": "1",
        "category": [
            1,
            1,
            2,
            2
        ]
    },
    {
        "hotel_id": "2",
        "category": [
            1,
            1,
            1,
            1
        ]
    },
    {
        "hotel_id": "3",
        "category": [
            1,
            1,
            1,
            1,
            1
        ]
    },
    {
        "hotel_id": "4",
        "category": [
            1
        ]
    }
]
```

I need prices inside the categories

I update my code now you can check what actually i am doing yes i use reduce method but can't able to get the actual result.

Comment: Have a look at the javascript reduce function https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce

Comment: Please can you post a more clearer expected output.

Comment: @user184994 now you can see my code yes i use reduce function but i have issue that i only able to handle hotels not categories

Comment: @ZaheerAhmad can you post expected output in this format too?

Comment: @charlietfl thanks for you guide line i add my code and rehearsed. kindly check now & yes i find the group by too but can't able to find good result. kindly if you know something let me know :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `reduce()` you aren't breaking out each category. I'm not 100% sure of output wanted for `category` , following uses an object with each unique value as key and array of prices for each category

```js
var hotel_to_values = myarray.reduce(function(obj, item) {
   const o = obj[item.hotel_id] = obj[item.hotel_id] || {};
   o[item.category] = (o[item.category]  || []).concat(item.price); 
  return obj;
}, {});

var hotels = Object.keys(hotel_to_values).map(function (key) {
    return {hotel_id: key, category: hotel_to_values[key]};
});


console.log(hotels)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100%!important;}
```

```html
<script>
  let myarray = [{
      price: 257,
      category: 1,
      hotel_id: 4
    },
    {
      price: 493,
      category: 1,
      hotel_id: 3
    },
    {
      price: 514,
      category: 1,
      hotel_id: 3
    },
    {
      price: 257,
      category: 1,
      hotel_id: 3
    },
    {
      price: 104,
      category: 1,
      hotel_id: 3
    },
    {
      price: 295,
      category: 1,
      hotel_id: 3
    },
    {
      price: 125,
      category: 1,
      hotel_id: 2
    },
    {
      price: 125,
      category: 1,
      hotel_id: 2
    },
    {
      price: 157,
      category: 1,
      hotel_id: 2
    },
    {
      price: 125,
      category: 1,
      hotel_id: 2
    },
    {
      price: 125,
      category: 1,
      hotel_id: 1
    },

    {
      price: 43,
      category: 1,
      hotel_id: 1
    },
    {
      price: 43,
      category: 2,
      hotel_id: 1
    },
    {
      price: 43,
      category: 2,
      hotel_id: 1
    }
  ];
</script>
```

Comment: I need the same output thanks for both things :) **charlietfl**

Comment: I removed `categories` property from the new object and works same with a bit less code